# Getting notification endlessly from GCM Intent Service in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have created a activity which got refreshes while a notification occurs but I am facing one problem which is that when a notification came it continues to send endless same notification. Earlier it was working fine but I made some changes and this had done. Please help me. I am attaching my code with it.

**Code for GCM IntentService class**

```
         @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msgg = intent.getStringExtra("message");

     final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification(this, msgg);


        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {

            sendNotification(this, msg);
            updateMyActivity(this,msgg);
            bundle.putString("result", msg);
            receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, bundle);

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            updateMyActivity(this,msgg);
            sendNotification(this, msg);



        }


}
```

**Send notification Code**

```
 private void sendNotification(Context context, String message) {

    Intent resultIntent;

    int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("afewtaps");
    notiStyle.setSummaryText(message);


    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle("afewtaps")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification from afewtaps")
            .setSound(alarmSound);



    resultIntent = new Intent(context,
            LoginActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            notify_no, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Show the max number of notifications here
    if (notify_no < 9) {
        notify_no = notify_no + 1;
    } else {
        notify_no = 0;
    }
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    nNotifyMgr.notify(notify_no + 2, nBuilder.build());


}
```

**Send message to broadcast**

```
    // This function will create an intent. This intent must take as parameter the "unique_name" that you registered your activity with
static void updateMyActivity(Context context, String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");

    //put whatever data you want to send, if any
    intent.putExtra("message", message);

    //send broadcast
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**this ends code for intent class.**

**now code of my activity**

```
         @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   // connectToDatabase();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"));
}

//Must unregister onPause()
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}


//This is the handler that will manager to process the broadcast intent
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        //do other stuff here

        connectToDatabase();


    }
};
```

Comment: Now GCM is depreciated you can use FCM for notification.

Comment: @Google  No i need to use GCM because it is on ending level .

Comment: What is the value of `notify_no`? Can't find it in the sendNotification method.

Comment: if (notify_no < 9) {
        notify_no = notify_no + 1;
    } else {
        notify_no = 0;
    }                     @NileshSingh

Comment: @MukeshMishra what's the initial value?

Comment: public static int notify_no = 0; @NileshSingh

Comment: @NileshSingh                        
public static int notify_no = 0;

Comment: Could you please add Log.e("tag", "method name") to every method of yours to find out which one is the culprit?

Comment: its onhandleintent.it is calling continously that is why all other functions are calling continuously @NileshSingh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131649/discussion-between-nilesh-singh-and-mukesh-mishra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So what is happening with your code is that you are sending a broadcast to your Receiver as well forcing the `onHandleIntent` to be invoked again, which in result calls the updateActivity method, which again broadcasts and loop continues endlessly.

In your `updateMyActivity` method, please change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent("myMessage");
```

The culprit here is

```
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
```

which calls the onHandleIntent when broadcasted.

Also, in your `onResume` method of the activity, please change the **TAG** to `myMessage`:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("myMessage"))
```

Comment: This is working only for first notification after that notification came for all but broadcast of that activity work only for first time