# How to create notification count on button in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to add one functionality i.e. I got a notification then a count will be displayed on button.

I have done like this if a notification arrives then I increase its value in shared preference and will show on button just as a badge count but problem is this I only want to remove that count when a user checked it how can i

Comment: post your code here

Comment: do you mean implement Badge to display count ?

Comment: Use a BroadcastReceiver to update the UI of your Activity every time a new Notification comes. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355335/getting-notification-endlessly-from-gcm-intent-service-in-android/41356399#41356399

Answer (score 0):

You can save one int variable in DB or Sharedpreference in android and on every notification increment that value and update that value on button.